# Switching From Online to Offline Stylesheets Based on Internet Availability

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, stylesheet

**Question / Problem:** Is it possible to **automatically switch between online stylesheet to offline stylesheets?** 
 
 For **example**, here in the office whenever I developed a site I need to connect to live bootstrap stylesheet, but whenever I go home I need offline stylesheet. I'm tired of commenting the stylesheets to be used. Is there any way?

**Conclusion:** Thanks to all, by using the code of linkinTED **I've solved this problem of mine**.

Comment: With only HTML and CSS (what you have tagged in your question) Im pretty sure you can't. If your able to use PHP, you could check if the external source is available, when not use the internal.

Comment: That would also be useful, can you help me? I can also use php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, that you are able to use PHP, you could use this code:

```
<?php

$extUrl = 'http://www.somesite.com/stylesheet.css';
$intUrl = 'css/stylesheet.css';

$url = ( @fopen( $extUrl, "r" ) ) ? $extUrl: $intUrl;

echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' . $url . '" />';

?>
```

Comment: This is good! Thanks LinkinTED, but the problem arises whenever the external url is not in use. It says

 fopen(http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.


I can use a code that will ignore errors, but is it okay?

Comment: @CaryBondoc, check the edit, added a `@` before the `fopen()` function to suppress the error message.

Comment: Now this is perfect. :) Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. You have to use a server-side technology/framework that allows to set up different configurations for your website and makes it easy to switch between one configuration and the other